# Python date-parsing

Tags: python, date, parsing

I have a problem with parsing python dates. The following code gives "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" when I call it like this

```
python2 dateFilter.py 2015-01-01 2015-02-01
```

## Source:

```
from os import sys
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

def dateParser(date):
    year = str(date[0:4])
    month = str(date[5:7])
    day = str(date[8:10])

    print(year)
    print(month)
    print(day)

    d = date(year, month, day)
    print(d)

    return

if __name__=="__main__":
    startDate = dateParser(sys.argv[1])
    endDate = dateParser(sys.argv[2])
```

The thing is I want to get dates form input and put it into date object

Comment: You're shadowing `from datetime import date` with `date`, the argument to `dateParser`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (note that it doesn't say *"edit [SOLVED] into the question title"*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter name `date` is shadowing your import: `from datetime import date`, change your parameter name to something like `dt` and you are good to go:

```
def dateParser(dt):
    year = str(dt[0:4])
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) rather than slice the string. Then your datetime object is constructed in just one step:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> d=dt.datetime.strptime('2015-02-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
>>> d.year, d.month, d.day
(2015, 2, 1)
```

Then your code would become:

```
from os import sys
import datetime as dt

def dateParser(date_str):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').date()    

if __name__=="__main__":
    startDate = dateParser('2015-01-01')
    endDate = dateParser('2015-02-01')
```